# How to keep cursor placement the same after replace script in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, textarea

I've tried several solutions to fix the error with cursor automatically going at the end of the line after replacing straight quotes into smart quotes.

I've already fixed the ones for comma, period, double spaces, semicolon, and em dash. But I cannot move on from the quotation marks.

**What my goal for it is:**

1. Auto replace straight quotes with smart quotes
2. Keep current position at the same location as it is.

```js
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
          var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

          var getCount = function (str, search) {
              return str.split(search).length - 1;
          };

          var replace = function (search, replaceWith) {
              if (typeof(search) == "object") {
                  area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
                  return;
              }
              if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
                  var start = area.selectionStart;
                  var end = area.selectionEnd;
                  var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
                  var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
                  area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
                  area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
                  area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
              }
          };

          area.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
              replace(" ,", ",");
              replace(" ;", ";");
              replace(" .", ".");
              replace("  ", " ");
              replace("--", "—");
              replace(/(^|[-\u2014\s(\["])'/g, "$1\u2018");
              replace(/'/g, "\u2019");
              replace(/(^|[-\u2014/\[(\u2018\s])"/g, "$1\u201c");
              replace(/"/g, "\u201d");
          });
        });
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Is this because of the regex used for the quotes that's why it's doing that? How can I do this properly?

Comment: You should store and recover `area.selection*` in any case, just like you already set `area.value` anew in any case.

Comment: How do I do that please? I'm sorry I didn't write those scripts on my own, I just tweak what I can tweak, but can't with that.

Comment: Then go ask the author (pun intended) of the code.